# Can we deploy WebGL applications as native iOS application using Enterprise Account

Tags: iphone, ios, webgl, enterprise

Can we deploy WebGL applications as native iOS application using Enterprise Account ?

My application will have a webview where I want to enable webgl

Comment: Doors opened now..WebGL is now supported in iOS Safari as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's no review for enterprise apps. You might use private APIs (with all the caveats associated to that).

Comment: Thankyou..I hope you are correct. I guess it is only the review process that is stopping us from using webgl.

Comment: There's no review, you have to distribute the app to employees by yourself. Most likely, some sort of MDM (mobile device management) software is used for that. If not, there's [HockeyKit](http://hockeykit.net) or just put the IPA and certificate on a webserver.

Comment: To add to the question - May be a dummy question again ?! Can my client have multiple enterprise accounts for his customers(if they dont have DUNS) ?

Comment: It's the other way around: the enterprises themselves have to apply for the account. If they don't have DUNS numbers, they're not eligible. Using a single enterprise program for employees of multiple enterprises is not allowed.

Comment: So that answered your question?

Comment: Ok...Got the Point !! Yes. Thankyou